# Mouse icon problem with dual monitors on Kubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, mouse, kubuntu

I am running Kubuntu 9.04 with the desktop extended across two monitors.  Everything is working well except, when I move the mouse pointer from monitor one to monitor two, an image of the mouse pointer remains on monitor one and vice versa.  So I always have one mouse pointer on each monitor at the same time.

Has anyone encountered this problem, or have any ideas for a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's [a known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/357901) caused by your GPU drivers

Perhaps you should check if you have the latest drivers? Before trying this possible solution I found.

However somebody posted a [possible fix for the same kind](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/357901/comments/33) of problem (though I can't confirm it's exactly the same problem):

> [Remove second cursor, when using
>   xinerama](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/26870925/178_second_cursor_fix.patch) (859 bytes, text/plain) i
>   applied patch and [added package in my
>   PPA:](https://launchpad.net/~m0sia/+archive/ppa)
>   https://launchpad.net/~m0sia/+archive/ppa
>
> But I can check if this patch works
>   only tomorrow at work.

Note: perhaps you should read the bug report first, to see if it makes sense.